# UnknownError when testing CloudFront Function via AWS SDK for Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-js

I have a CloudFront Function and I'm trying to test it using AWS SDK for Javascript. This is my code:

```
const client = new CloudFrontClient(); // configured using env variables
const eventObject = require("./my_event.json");
const input = {
  Name: "my-function",
  IfMatch: etag, // I get this value from describe-function
  EventObject: Uint8Array.from(eventObject)
};
const command = new TestFunctionCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
console.log(response);
```

When I run it, I get a server error:

```
 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 500,
    requestId: '...',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 3,
    totalRetryDelay: 234
  },
  Type: 'Receiver',
  Code: 'InternalError'
}
```

`my_event.json` has a valid format. When I run the same command with the AWS CLI, it works properly:

```
$ aws cloudfront test-function --name my_function --if-match whatever --event-object fileb://my_event.json
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I debug this?

It works properly